# Why strlen() is giving wrong value for a char array with undefined array size?

Tags: c, strlen

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
  int a[]={1,2,3,4};
  int size= sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
  printf("\nSize/capacity of integer type array(with no limit) %d\n",size);

  int a1[6]={1,2,3,4};
  int size1= sizeof(a1)/sizeof(int);
  printf("\nSize/capacity of integer type array(with a limit of 7) %d\n",size1);

printf("\n");

  char b[7]={'a','b','c','d','e'};
  int size2= sizeof(b)/sizeof(char);
  int length=strlen(b);
  printf("\nSize/capacity of char type array(with a limit of 7) %d\n",size2);
  printf("\nNumber of char type data in the array %d\n",length);

  char br[]={'k','l'};
  int size3= sizeof(br)/sizeof(char);
  int length1=strlen(br);
  printf("\nSize/capacity of char type array(with no limit) %d\n",size3);
  printf("\nNumber of char type data in the array length1 %d\n",length1);    //answer should have been 2

 return 0;
}`
```

It gave me 7 as an output for the value length1. When I commented out the upper block(above the initialization of br[]) the array length came out as 3. I want to know why this is happening and the solution. I am new to this but thanks in advance.

The output for the code above:

Size/capacity of integer type array(with no limit) 4

Size/capacity of integer type array(with a limit of 7) 6

Size/capacity of char type array(with a limit of 7) 7

Number of char type data in the array 5

Size/capacity of char type array(with no limit) 2

Number of char type data in the array length1 7

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you're getting weird behavior in C, and something in your code isn't defined, you can probably chalk up the weird behavior to Undefined Behavior.

Comment: `strlen` only works for C-style strings: those that terminate with `\0`. Your `b` array does not. Hence, undefined behavior. There is no way to magically "get" length of a string unless you know something about the string for sure. Like the fact that it terminates with `\0`, which is the case for string literals (`"ab"` is actually array of three characters) and most strings that the standard library manipulate.

Comment: Don't use `strlen` on an array which isn't zero terminated

Comment: The definition `char br[]={'k','l'};` is equal to `char br[2]={'k','l'};`.

Comment: It's a good idea to read the documentation about functions you're using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strlen works by looking for the null terminator '\0', and your character arrays don't end with a null terminator character.

Change this

```
char br[]={'k','l'};
```

to this

```
char br[]={'k','l', '\0'};
```

and make a similar change to b (plus adding 1 to the size of the array) and see what happens.

Comment: Or more concisely: `char br[] = "kl";`

Comment: Thanks that helped. And adding 1 to the size of the array b is for the \0 correct? But even if leave that unchanged I am still getting the correct value for the output. Any reason behind that?

Comment: Yes, it is. The null terminator takes up space, though strlen doesn't count it. Yes, this means that if use strlen to get a string's size in preparation for copying it, you'll need to add 1 to the result from strlen to have enough room for the string itself and the null terminator.

Answer (score 4):

`strlen` doesn't tell you the length of a character array, it tells you the length of a null-terminated string.  The array `br` does not hold a string because it's only long enough to hold the individual characters that were used to initialize it, and those don't include a byte with value 0.

If you used a string literal to initialize the array instead of an initializer list of characters:

```
char br[]="kl";
```

Then the array would be sized to include the terminating null byte that's part of the string literal, and you can then use string functions on it.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ man strlen:
[...]
The strlen() function computes the length of the string s
[...]
$ man string:
[...]
The string functions manipulate strings that are terminated by a null byte.
[...]
```

"A char array" which ends in `4`, `'e'`, or `'l'` is not null-terminated, therefore not a string, therefore calling strlen on one is UB.

Comment: `char a[] = { '!', 0, 34, 'e' };` is a `char` array that ends in `'e'` but that contains a null-terminated string. A proper statement is that an array that does not contain a null character does not contain a null-terminated string.